# Windows console escapes sprop-parameter-sets

Tags: windows, console, h.264, gstreamer, video-encoding

I'm using the Windows console to launch my GStreamer video pipeline. The video consists of an H264 encoded stream that is received via UDP. In order to mux and record the stream I must provide detailed info about the stream's properties - among them a parameter called **sprop-parameter-sets** (line 4):

```
C:\gst-launch -v udpsrc port=5000 ! application/x-rtp, media=(string)video,
clock-rate=(int)90000, 
encoding-name=(string)H264, 
sprop-parameter-sets=(string)\"Z0LAFdkBQfsBEAAAAwAXc1lAAPFi5IA\\=\\,aMuMsg\\=\\=\", 
payload=(int)96, 
ssrc=(uint)2823396101, 
clock-base=(uint)3965093735, 
seqnum-base=(uint)31989
! gstrtpjitterbuffer ! rtph264depay ...
```

As you can see, the parameter already contains a number of escaped chars. I'm told this works in Linux - in Windows however I get an error message that the caps (or rather the parameter) cannot be parsed. I'm aware of the MS-console's various escapes (^\...) yet didn't find the problem. 
Is there a Windows guru out there who can help me format the parameter correctly?

Comment: No I didnt, launched Pipeline from code instead.

Comment: I'm hoping to emulate you.  Did you dump the whole pipeline string into gst_parse_launch?  Or have to build the pipeline by hand (in code)?